# python PIL.Image give me incorrect tiff

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I use PIL.Image library to open a tif file and convert it to numpy array:

```
 PIL.ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True # because my tif file is big
 im = PIL.Image.open('1.tif')
 arr = numpy.asarray(im)
```

I found weird result, so I did the following test:

```
 im1 = PIL.ImageFile.fromarray(arr,"CMYK") # tif file is CMYK value
 im1.save('new.tif')
```

It turned out that the new tif file doesn't look like the original tif file. Suppose the 1.tif looks like A, then new.tif looks like several A tiled together, each of A is smaller, but the total size is the same. I don't know where I do it wrong.

---

Update:
Both x and y direction, the image is repeated 4 times, so together is 16 times. But the total size of the new tif remains the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Please share the TIFF file.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the tiff file is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwyixv6r3dq1hli/off.tif?dl=0

Comment: First, no need to change `LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES`. Your file is neither truncated nor big. Second, PIL/Pillow does not handle planar CMYK images. You might want to report the issue at <https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues>.

Comment: If I didn't set LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES, it will give me error. For the second comment, I found the api document Image.fromarray indeed support "CMYK" color space. If Pillow doesn't hand cmyk images, do you know any other library I can use instead of PIL/Pillow?  Thank you!